# Have Goldman Sachs Quantitative Strategies Research Notes been published as a book or a comprehensive collection?

Tags: volatility, research, hedging, quantitative

Back in the 90's, Goldman Sachs (publicly?) released a series called "Quantitative Strategies Research Notes" — mostly technical papers on topic. [Emanuel Derman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Derman) co-authored almost all of them.

Some of them are available online:

- [Regimes of Volatility](http://www.javaquant.net/papers/derman_1999_regimes.pdf)
- [Trading and Hedging Local Volatility](http://www.emanuelderman.com/media/gs-trading_and_hedging.pdf)
- [How to Value and Hedge Options on Foreign Indexes](https://buildingarks.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/gs-foreign-indices-quanto-compo.pdf)
- [Strike-Adjusted Spread](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/cap/zhou-paper.pdf)
- [The Local Volatility Surface](http://bfi.cl/papers/Derman%20Kani%20Zou%201995%20-%20Local%20volatility%20surface%20Unlocking%20the%20information%20in%20index%20option%20prices.pdf)

But 15 more papers are apparently missing.

Did anyone see them published, perhaps, as a book? Or just a comprehensive collection?

### References

This is the latest list of the publications that I took from a late 1999 paper:

- Understanding Guaranteed Exchange-Rate Contracts In Foreign Stock Investments.
  Emanuel Derman, Piotr Karasinski and Jeffrey Wecker
- Valuing and Hedging Outperformance Options.
  Emanuel Derman
- Pay-On-Exercise Options.
  Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Ins and Outs of Barrier Options.
  Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Volatility Smile and Its Implied Tree.
  Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- Static Options Replication.
  Emanuel Derman, Deniz Ergener and Iraj Kani
- Enhanced Numerical Methods for Options with Barriers.
  Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani, Deniz Ergener and Indrajit Bardhan
- The Local Volatility Surface: Unlocking the Information in Index Option Prices.
  Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani and Joseph Z. Zou
- Implied Trinomial Trees of the Volatility Smile.
  Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani and Neil Chriss
- Model Risk.
  Emanuel Derman,
- Trading and Hedging Local Volatility.
  Iraj Kani, Emanuel Derman and Michael Kamal
- Investing in Volatility.
  Emanuel Derman, Michael Kamal, Iraj Kani, John McClure, Cyrus Pirasteh and Joseph Zou
- Is the Volatility Skew Fair?
  Emanuel Derman, Michael Kamal, Iraj Kani and Joseph Zou
- Stochastic Implied Trees: Arbitrage Pricing with Stochastic Term and Strike Structure of Volatility.
  Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Patterns of Change in Implied Index Volatilities.
  Michael Kamal and Emanuel Derman
- Predicting the Response of Implied Volatility to Large Index Moves: An October 1997 S&P Case Study.
  Emanuel Derman and Joe Zou
- How to Value and Hedge Options on Foreign Indexes.
  Kresimir Demeterfi
- Regimes of Volatility: Some Observations on the Variation of S&P 500 Implied Volatilities.
  Emanuel Derman

Comment: GSAM also published a book on asset management to compete with Barclay's Global Investors(now BlackRock), http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Investment-Management-Equilibrium-Approach/dp/0471124109

Comment: Anton I edited the question by inserting the moneyscience link in which **should** be listed all references!

Comment: This is actually a very good question. I have access to the GS quant research database and they are not even available there (just checked).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Many of them are on my website at [emanuelderman.com](http://emanuelderman.com/).  Others I probably have anyway. Feel free to email me

Comment: Is it really you, THE Emanuel Derman? it is a great honour to have you here! A very warm welcome to you! :-)

Comment: A great honour indeed, welcome to Quant.SE, Emanual Derman!

Answer (score 11):

I had read some of them; actually, it does not exist an on-line library that collected them (or, better, it existed [here](http://www.gs.com/qs), but it seems the website does not work anymore).

I reported here below some of them that you did not find:

- [More Than You Ever Wanted To Know* About Volatility Swaps](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/IC_Volatility/IC_Volatility_Docs/Literature/Goldman_VarSwaps.pdf)
- [Model Risk](http://www.emanuelderman.com/media/gs-model_risk.pdf)
- [The Volatility Smile And Its implied Tree](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~mordecki/hk/derman-kani.pdf)
- [Enhanced Numerical Methods
  for Options with Barriers](http://ciberconta.unizar.es/bolsa/enhaced.pdf)

Those are ones I read and I know, while, here below, you can find other papers of that series:

> Emanuel Derman and Joe Zou, “Is the Volatility Skew Fair?” Goldman
>   Sachs Quantitative Strategies Research Notes, 1997.

**EDIT**: the [moneyscience](http://www.moneyscience.com/pg/bookmarks/Admin/read/211861/goldman-sachs-quantitative-strategies-research-notes) provides a list of them, but I'm not sure about its completeness.

**EDIT 2**: This is the latest list of the publications that I took from a late 1999 paper:

- Understanding Guaranteed Exchange-Rate Contracts In Foreign Stock
- Investments Emanuel Derman, Piotr Karasinski and Jeffrey Wecker
- Valuing and Hedging Outperformance Options Emanuel Derman
- Pay-On-Exercise Options Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Ins and Outs of Barrier Options Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Volatility Smile and Its Implied Tree Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- Static Options Replication Emanuel Derman, Deniz Ergener and Iraj Kani
- Enhanced Numerical Methods for Options with Barriers Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani, Deniz Ergener and Indrajit Bardhan
- The Local Volatility Surface: Unlocking the Information in Index Option Prices Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani and Joseph Z. Zou
- Implied Trinomial Trees of the Volatility Smile Emanuel Derman, Iraj Kani and Neil Chriss
- Model Risk Emanuel Derman,
- Trading and Hedging Local Volatility Iraj Kani, Emanuel Derman and Michael Kamal
- Investing in Volatility Emanuel Derman, Michael Kamal, Iraj Kani, John McClure, Cyrus Pirasteh and Joseph Zou
- Is the Volatility Skew Fair? Emanuel Derman, Michael Kamal, Iraj Kani and Joseph Zou
- Stochastic Implied Trees: Arbitrage Pricing with Stochastic Term and Strike Structure of Volatility Emanuel Derman and Iraj Kani
- The Patterns of Change in Implied Index Volatilities Michael Kamal and Emanuel Derman
- Predicting the Response of Implied Volatility to Large Index Moves: An October 1997 S&P Case Study Emanuel Derman and Joe Zou
- How to Value and Hedge Options on Foreign Indexes Kresimir Demeterfi
  Regimes of Volatility: Some Observations on the Variation of S&P 500 Implied Volatilities Emanuel Derman

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the `qs` link! A 2001 snapshot is available via archive.org : http://web.archive.org/web/20010207223703/http://www.gs.com/qs/ . (I think you could add it to your answer.) These are excellent papers, although not the series I mentioned. After your link to Moneyscience, I also added the latest list of the series to my question (it seems to be more complete than that of Moneyscience). Thanks again!

Comment: Nice Job @Anton!

Comment: @Anton edited answer!